# Need Regular expression that should allow only valid Page Numbers like 1,2,3,4-5 with max 3 digits length of each page number (1-999)

Tags: javascript, .net, regex, validation

My textbox should allow only valid page numbers like

```
1,2,3,4-9 
2,8
1-3,5
5-7
7,8-6
1-3,5
1,2
2,3,4,5-6,7
10
11-15
22,25
```

Code:

```
// Regex
var pageNumberHypenComma = new RegExp("^[0-9]+(?:,[0-9-]+)*(?:-[0-9,]+)*$");  

// Value of Page Numbers
var txtMemberPages = "1,2,3,4-9,12";

// Regex checking
if (!pageNumberHypenComma.test(txtMemberPages)) {
    alert('Invalid Page Number(s)'); 
    return false;
}
```

Above regular expression is not working. need help

Comment: Why C#? The code you have is JS. The regex must be `^[0-9]{1,3}(?:[,-][0-9]{1,3})*$`

Comment: Is 4-9-4 a valid range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The additional requirements to your question are:

- Values cannot be with zero
- Values should be between 1 and 125
- Range should only occur in between two numbers.

Use

```
var rng = '(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\\d|1[01]\\d|12[0-5])'; // This is a number from 1 to 125
var pageNumberHypenComma = new RegExp("^" + rng + "(?:-" + rng + ")?(?:," + rng + "(?:-" + rng + ")?)*$");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/al6c61/5)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|1[01]\d|12[0-5])` - `1` to `125`
- `(?:-(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|1[01]\d|12[0-5]))?` - an optional group matching `-` and a number from `1` to `125`
- `(?:,(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|1[01]\d|12[0-5])(?:-(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|1[01]\d|12[0-5]))?)*` - 0 or more sequences of

  - `,` - comma
  - `(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|1[01]\d|12[0-5])` - a number from `1` to `125`
  - `(?:-(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|1[01]\d|12[0-5]))?` - an optional sequence of `-` and the number from `1` to `125`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: @Raseeth Try `/^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:[,-][1-9][0-9]{0,2})*$/`

Comment: is it possible to validation like page number should not exceed 125 ?

Comment: @Raseeth See [this generator](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/), replace `[1-9][0-9]{0,2}` with `(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|1[01]\d|12[0-5])`. I.e. `/^(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|1[01]\d|12[0-5])(?:[,-](?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|1[01]\d|12[0-5]))*$/`

Comment: @Raseeth You should have explained every requirement in your question. I updated all the parts of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the ranges of the pages can contain only a single hyphen, you could match 1+ digits followed by an optional part to match a hyphen and 1 - 3 digits.

Then repeat that pattern 0+ times prepended by a comma.

```
^\d{1,3}(?:-\d{1,3})?(?:,\d{1,3}(?:-\d{1,3})?)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `\d{1,3}(?:-\d{1,3})?` Match 1-3 digits and optionally match `-` and 1-3 digits
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `,\d{1,3}(?:-\d{1,3})?` Match comma, 1-3 digits and optionally match `-` and 1-3 digits
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w2ttMD/1)

```js
var pageNumberHypenComma = new RegExp("^\\d{1,3}(?:-\\d{1,3})?(?:,\\d{1,3}(?:-\\d{1,3})?)*$");
[
  "1,2,3,4-9-4",
  "1,2,3,4-9",
  "2,8",
  "1-3,5",
  "5-7",
  "7,8-6",
  "1-3,5",
  "1,2",
  "2,3,4,5-6,7",
  "10",
  "11-15",
  "22,25",
  "1,2,3,4-9,12"
  
].forEach(s => console.log(s + " ==> " + pageNumberHypenComma.test(s)))
```

To match only pagenumbers greater than 0, you could match a digit 1-9 followed by 2 optional digits:

```
^[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:-[1-9]\d{0,2})?(?:,[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:-[1-9]\d{0,2})?)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w2ttMD/2)

```js
var pageNumberHypenComma = new RegExp("^[1-9]\\d{0,2}(?:-[1-9]\\d{0,2})?(?:,[1-9]\\d{0,2}(?:-[1-9]\\d{0,2})?)*$");
[
  "1,2,3,4-9-4",
  "0",
  "0-1, 3",
  "1,2,3,4-9",
  "2,8",
  "1-3,5",
  "5-7",
  "7,8-6",
  "1-3,5",
  "1,2",
  "2,3,4,5-6,7",
  "10",
  "11-15",
  "22,25",
  "1,2,3,4-9,12",
  "0",
  "0-1,3"

].forEach(s => console.log(s + " ==> " + pageNumberHypenComma.test(s)))
```

Using a range from 1 - 125 instead of 999, the pattern would look like:

```
^(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|1[01]\d|12[0-5])(?:-(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|1[01]\d|12[0-5]))?(?:,(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|1[01]\d|12[0-5])(?:-(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|1[01]\d|12[0-5]))?)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sn6z1w/1/)

```js
var pageNumberHypenComma = new RegExp("^(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\\d|1[01]\\d|12[0-5])(?:-(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\\d|1[01]\\d|12[0-5]))?(?:,(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\\d|1[01]\\d|12[0-5])(?:-(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\\d|1[01]\\d|12[0-5]))?)*$");
[
  "1,2,3,4-9",
  "2,8",
  "1-3,5",
  "5-7",
  "7,8-6",
  "1-3,5",
  "1,2",
  "2,3,4,5-6,7",
  "10",
  "11-15",
  "22,25",
  "0",
  "0-1,3",
  "1,2,3,4-9",
  "1,2,3,4-9-4",
  "1",
  "126",
  "125",
  "10",
  "1000",
  "1,4,124-125,4",
  "1,4,125-126"
].forEach(s => console.log(s + " ==> " + pageNumberHypenComma.test(s)))
```

Comment: @Raseeth Is 4-9-4 a valid range?

Comment: @Raseeth You could match 1-9 with 2 optional digits `\d{0,2}` See https://regex101.com/r/w2ttMD/2

Comment: @Raseeth Is 4-9-4 a valid range?   IS NOT VALID

Comment: @Raseeth Did you validate that for both answers?

Comment: is it possible to validation like page number should not exceed 125 ?